# Delete folder in php

Tags: php

I am trying to delete a folder [using this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334398/how-to-delete-a-folder-with-contents-using-php/1334425#1334425) :

```
function Delete($path)
{
    if (is_dir($path) === true)
    {
        $files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));

        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
                Delete(realpath($path) . '/' . $file);
        }

        return rmdir($path);
    }

    else if (is_file($path) === true)
    {
        return unlink($path);
    }

    return false;
}

Delete('tmp');
```

It works in my Xampp server, but not on my webserver. I have changed the permissions of the folder and of the file it contains to 0777. So it should be writable(or in this case erasable) but nothing happens. I have even tryied giving the absolute path of the folder as the parameter of the function, but still nothing.Any ideas?

Comment: Any error messages? You should be getting some.

Comment: Try adding at the top  `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`    and see if any errors decide to show up.

Comment: No. Still nothing. Just a few notice messages that I was expecting. But they are not related.

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
function delTree($dir)
{
 $files = glob( $dir . '*', GLOB_MARK );
 foreach( $files as $file 
 {
  if( is_dir( $file ) )
   delTree( $file );
  else
   @unlink( $file );
 }

 if( is_dir($dir) ) rmdir( $dir );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it return false? Or it returns true but doesn't actually remove?

Normally I'd just guess it's a permissions problem.

Try making a folder with mkdir from PHP so PHP is the owner (so to speak) and try to remove that with your function.

If it works, it's a permissions/owner issue.

Comment: I have tried this: if(mkdir("tmp", 0777))
echo('works');
else echo('nope');
if(Delete('tmp'))
echo('yes');
else echo('no');
But nothing happens. It's not making the folder. And it's not showing anything.

Comment: Are you sure your host allows those functions?

Comment: Yes, I just tried making a new php file and making a folder using the new php file. It worked. Interesting enough, altough I used mkdir("tmp",0777) it created a tmp folder with 0755 persmissions which are the default. Am I using the mkdir function wrong?Should the permissions value be in quotes?

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this code

```
<?php
$files = glob('application/*'); foreach($files as $file){  if(is_file($file)) unlink($file);  }
?>
```

Or,

```
   function viewDir($path) {
    return is_file($path) ?
            @unlink($path) :
            array_map(__FUNCTION__, glob($path.'/*')) == @rmdir($path);
}
$dir=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/xxxx/xxxx";
echo $dir;
viewDir($dir);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be some files are opened using php like fopen and that time it will not delete the folder or directory. I have faced the same issue when I tried to delete a file/folder

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
<?php
function delete_directory($target) {
         if (is_dir($target))
           $dir_handle = opendir($target);
     if (!$dir_handle)
          return false;
     while($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
           if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                if (!is_dir($dirname."/".$file))
                     unlink($dirname."/".$file);
                else
                     delete_directory($target.'/'.$file);
           }
     }
     closedir($dir_handle);
     rmdir($target);
     return true;
}

?>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this line of code to delete a folder or folder files
I hope this will help you

```
function deleteAll($str) {
        if (is_file($str)) {
            return unlink($str);
        }
        elseif (is_dir($str)) {
            $scan = glob(rtrim($str,'/').'/*');
            foreach($scan as $index=>$path) {
                $this->deleteAll($path);
            }            
            return @rmdir($str);
        }
    }
```