# delete all files in a folder with php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to delete a folder with contents using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334398/how-to-delete-a-folder-with-contents-using-php)

hi,

is it possible to delete all children within a parent directory and then delete the the parent directory in php?

Edited:

When i use scan dir why does the first 2 elements of the array show '.', '..'?:

```
> Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => evga-nvidia-graphics-card4d0fe6868d2f8.jpg [3] => image4d0eaafb920a0.png [4] => image4d0eab086a106.png )
```

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first elements in your array (`.` and  `..`) are references to the directory itself (`.`) and to its parent directory (`..`). Every non-root directory in your filesystem will have both of them. They are usually ignored by hand in this kind of scripts.

If you use a [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) you can tell if the current element you're iterating over is either `.` or `..` with the `isDot()` function.